# Is deleting Gmail thread specific enough to delete only messages from a specific email?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I made the following algorithm in Google Script which deletes all mails from a specific adress from all folders:

```
function deleteForever() {
  var labelName
  labelName="some_mail_address"
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in: all from:" + labelName);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("me", threads[i].getId());
  }
}
```

Is this safe to use for my gmail account? (With a trigger such that it runs every minute)

In particular, I am wondering whether a thread can contain multiple mails, and whether this can result in deleting mails which are not from the unwanted sender.

Also, I have seen "in: anywhere" on some webpages. Is this different from "in: all"?

Comment: You can create a list of current email addresses to become an email whitelist and only delete emails that are not on the whitelist.  Personally, I would not run a script every minute.  I have some thing that runs as an addon and I can use it at will whenever I return to gmail I keep an email in the inbox all of the time so that I can launch it easily.

Comment: The goal is not seeiing the mails from the particular sender anymore, so manually running the script is not an option.

Comment: The whitelist may work so that the computation time is smaller and it is safer. However, maybe it is even better to create a filter that labels incoming mails from the specific adress, and then run the script only on those messages.

Comment: Spam filters can get very complicated as you will undoubtedly come to realize.  But if you wish to go that way good luck.  Personally, I use the whitelist method and I collect just enough information to know if I should have included emails that didn't pass in my white list.   The answer you have chosen seems a little bit to threatening for my taste.  I do delete the messages permanently but never fear the chances are you will see them again.   The quota issue is true but you can decrease the poll rate.  I would not say that it is not safe.  The polling rate is rather high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

It's not "safe" because:

1. the thread id is the same id for the first thread message but the first message might be from other sender.
2. the message will be deleted permanently
3. running a script every minute might consume the daily quota so you might first getting error messages and lately the trigger might be disabled due to having so many errors.

`in:anywhere` is not the same as `in:all`. The first will return threads labeled as spam and trash but the later doesn't.

---

1. Instead using the thread id, iterate over the thread messages to check the sender, if it matches then "delete" the message
2. Instead of using "remove" use "trash"
3. If you use "trash" instead of "remove" don't use "in:anywhere" otherwise the same message will be processed over an over until it's deleted permanently.
4. Instead of using a trigger scheduled to run every minute, run it every ten minutes or use a lower frequency if you plan to use other time driven triggers.

Related

- [Same thread id does not return the same message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31326237/1595451)
- [Unthread or permanently delete individual gmail messages, without turning off threading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57778990/1595451)